# What causes regions of improperly-lit terrain when my pixel light count is below 4?

Tags: unity, lighting

My Unity3d game has a strange bug where if you have the pixel light count set below 4, these strange boxes appear on the terrain.  Because this game is going to be for mobile, if I set the pixel light count too high, won't run fast enough.

The screenshot will show you what I mean:

[image]

You can see this box on the left of the image where light is entering, I want light to enter all around the coin. How can I fix or prevent this?

Comment: You're talking about the brighter region on the left of the image, right?

Comment: @JoshPetrie Yes, this is for all the point lights.

Comment: @JoshPetrie I want light to be all around the yellow coin, but it looks like the light is only able to enter through that square.

Comment: I think I see what you mean; feel free to edit your question further if my edits are inaccurate or misleading. I don't actually have any idea what the problem is though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You have 1 pixel light in the scene for every coin, I see four coins in the scene.
- You have your quality settings set to 1 pixel light.

This means that every mesh will pick the *nearest* 1 pixel light to use for illumination and ignore the rest.  The nearest light to the plane on the left of the image is the light we can see.  For the other three planes, that light is not the nearest.

Comment: Thank you but, I need to make the game fast so that it doesn't lag, the unity editor warned me that the game would lag if I had more than one pixel light count.  It there any way to get around this issue?

Comment: @SkrillexNukehulk Do you need the lights on your coins to be pixel lights?  Do you need them to be lights at all?  Do you suffer performance problems making them pixel lights on your target min spec machine with the maximum number of coins you expect to have on screen.  Are you in forward or deferred rendering?  You can fix the problem easily enough one way or another, it just depends on your use cases.